# Custom domain name to serve Python packages from Google Artifact Registry?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

We're serving Python packages through Google's Artifact Registry. Actually the URL is the "default" one, so:

```
https://[REGION].pkg.dev/[PROJECT_ID]/.....
```

But what if we wanted to use a custom domain name? For example, we'd like to serve packages from a custom domain link like:

```
https://[MY-CUSTOM-DOMAIN]/...
```

Is there an official way to do that? What are my options?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Did you try already something and get any error? So you don't want to use Google Artifact Registry but you want to get packages from other source? You want to use GKE, GCE?

Answer (score 1):

We got an "official" answer from a `Google Cloud Community Team member`, please see [this link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Custom-domain-name-to-serve-Python-packages-from-Google-Artifact/m-p/184239#M437).

It pretty answer my question.

> There is no official support for custom domains in AR but you can run a reverse proxy on Cloud Run (which supports Custom domains). This article might help - [Hack your own custom domains for Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hack-your-own-custom-domains-container-registry)